# How to use short names for "Figure" using the hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the hyperref package to write a document. I am referencing my figures using `\autoref{fig:my_figure_label}`

As an example:

```
The results are shown in \autoref{fig:termperature_field}
```

The output is:

> The results are shown in Figure 1.

How can I force it to produce short name for the word "**Figure**" so it appears as "**Fig.**" instead:

> The results are shown in Fig. 1.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hyperref` uses `\<type>autorefname` to determine how to call those.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Fig.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      A duck.%
      \label{fig:duck}%
    }%
\end{figure}

See \autoref{fig:duck}.
\end{document}
```

gives what you want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the `cleveref` package over `hyperref`’s `\autoref`. In addition to supporting abbreviated label names out of the box, it provides other useful features as well. `texdoc cleveref` for the details.